# Simple query and loop, unexpected result

Tags: php

This is a small subfunction in one of my files.

Let's assume we have two tables with the following fields

Table 1) products, with the fields sku & rangeid

table 2) pricelist, with the fields sku & onpricelist

My code basically takes a rangeid, loads all products in that range, then calls onList to check if any of those products have a 1 in onpricelist, if any of the products in the designated rangeid have the flag of 1 checkHasProducts should return 1. The onList function works as expected but for some reason the checkHasProducts function returns 1 regardless of what is returned from onList. onList can literally return a random string and checkHasProducts will still return 1.

Here is the code

```
function checkHasProducts($rid) {


    $db = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

        $sql = "SELECT * from products WHERE rangeid = '$rid'";
        $result = $db->query($sql);
        $exists = 0;
        if($result === false) { return 0; } else { 
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                if(onList($row['sku']) == "on") {
                    $exists = 1;
                }
            }
                return $exists;
        }
}

function onList($sku) {

    $db = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

        $sql = "SELECT * from pricelist WHERE sku = '$sku'";
        $result = $db->query($sql);

        if($result === false) { return 0; } else { 
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                    if($row['onpricelist'] == "1") {
                        return "on";
                    } else { return 0; }
                }
        }
}
```

I'm sure it's something simple but I've been starting at this for hours now, any assistance would be appreciated.

Example row dump from both functions

```
array (size=xx)
  'prodid' => string '139' (length=3)
  'rangeid' => string '14' (length=2)
  'sku' => string 'ABC123456' (length=10)

array (size=x)
  'priceid' => string '129' (length=3)
  'sku' => string 'ABC123456' (length=10)
  'onpricelist' => string '0' (length=1)
```

Comment: what is the type of onpricelist field in the database?

Comment: Dump $row ($row['onpricelist']) so at least we can see some data. Also there must be a JOIN somewhere that would save you this trouble...

Comment: @Okneloper it is set to int

Comment: can you also give us some example rows from the table (with data that would trigger a result of 0 instead of 1)

Comment: @Eric example dump above

Comment: @Gavriel example dump above

Comment: How do you call the second function?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky in the IF statement of the first function

Comment: In that statement change that `==` to `===` and your problem will be solved. If it does, come again to ask how :)

Comment: Database queries in loops are bad for performance; you should rather rewrite this to a JOIN that fetches all the necessary information from the database in one go.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Here I am to ask how!?. understood Cbroe, it's only going to be running 6/7 queries in the loop at any time.

Comment: I gave an answer but it is wrong, I missed the part in while loop onList() function triggering. @user1372212 is there any relation between pricelist and products table ? Inner join may be a good solution.

Comment: @FeyyazEsatoğlu the sku field would be a link

Answer (score 0):

Here's your issue:

```
if($row['onpricelist'] == "1") {
   return "on";
} else { return 0; }
```

This code returns 0 not even going though all the records in the result. Then

```
onList($row['sku']) == "on"
```

is `0 == "on"`, php casts "on" to 0, so the result is always true.

You need to remove the `else { return 0; }` part from the while loop and add 
`return 0` at the end of the function, ie after the loop.

Comment: I have made the suggested change not it has not changed the output nor do I understand how it could. in the second function the query will never return more than one result

Comment: I would ask for the new code, but there's no place to paste it. There could be still a mistake in the code.

Comment: Also, see this for how return operator works: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php
You can't return more than one result, true, but return stop executing the function (and your loop).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't directly asked but you can achieve the same results with more performance, and it solves your problem also like @Okneloper said.
Edited answer :

```
    <?php
function checkHasProductsOnLisByRid($rid) {  
    $db = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    $result = $db->query(sprintf("SELECT COUNT(pr.*) from products pr INNER JOIN pricelist pl ON pl.sku = pr.sku WHERE pr.rangeid = '%d' and pl.onpricelist = 1", $rid));
     if (!empty($result)) {
        $result = (bool) $result->fetch_row();
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: 2 connections = typo?

Comment: @FeyyazEsatoğlu The two function's don't seem to be linked from the above?

Comment: Yeah @user1372212 I missed the onList it was trigerring in while loop could you provide table information ? is pricelist and products are related with/via id ? I can edit my answer in that direction.

Comment: @user1372212 I updated answer could please try it again ?

Comment: @FeyyazEsatoğlu just attempting to integrate now, seems to only be returning false.

Comment: You may check your database, with your id there may be not qualify records which make return this function as true.

Comment: Query Explanation : We are counting product table records which a record's sku number is in pricelist and onpricelist = 1 . If any records qualify this query it will return count, we are type casting to boolean 1 or 0 as function return. How do you use this function in your script ? Could you share with gist/pastebin ?

Comment: Coud you check again ? @user1372212 I fixed some typo and fix. I tried this query in similiar table. It works properly.

Comment: @FeyyazEsatoğlu Hey, I had modify the query into some existing code, please see the answer i posted below

Comment: I see, do you have any other problems ? If not please vote an answer which solves your problem to help people who has the similar needs.

Answer (score 0):

Correct Answer came in from comments from Hanky 웃 Panky to change

```
if(onList($row['sku']) == "on") {
```

to

```
if(onList($row['sku']) === "on") {
```

Also as a better way of doing it Feyyaz Esatoğlu assisted in me reaching the following conclusion

```
 $sql = "SELECT * from products pr INNER JOIN pricelist pl ON pl.sku = pr.sku WHERE pr.rangeid = '$rid' and pl.onpricelist = '1'";

    $db = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($row_cnt != "0") { $row_cnt = "1"; }
    return $row_cnt;
```